# Javascript: passing context properties into function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm looking for a way to inject properties from "this" into local function scope, so i dont need write 'this.' when referencing to this properties.

Exact details are displayed in this code http://jsfiddle.net/wwVhu/3/, look at this part

```
    ...
    //it's how it works
    doStuff: function(param) { $('#output').html(this.value + param) }

    //it's how i want it work - without referencing to this
    //doStuff: function(param) { $('#output').html(value + param) }
```

I know it could be achieved by wrapping function code in "with(this) { ... }", but what are other options?

Writing "with(this)" in the beginning of every method or using js aop is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Normally, I would say just add your `value` outside the `fields` definition, so it's scoped to the anonymous function (basically it becomes a "private" variable). It would, however, require you to write accessor methods for the variables. But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your framework, so I'm adding it just as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? It's namespaced because it makes sence. `this` references to the element the listener is listening on. And it contains a lot more information than just the value.

If you want the value in another variable, you can do:

```
var value = this.value
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically four options:

1. You keep it the way it is. Context and local scope are different objects, combining them is bad practice and leads to collisions.
2. You add the value property as the 2nd parameter to the `doStuff` function.
3. You nickname `this` with a shorter identifier. I often find myself use `$t`.
4. You use `with(this) $('#output').html(value + param);`. This is a bad coding practice, as explained in `1)`. Your code becomes broken the second there is a `param` property in `this`.